# How can I fix this table so that the mass in the first row stays on top of the first three columns and mass 2 over the other three

Tags: tables, multicolumn

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
     \hline
     \multicolumn{3}{|||c|}{Mass 1}
     \multicolumn{3}{c||}{Mass 2}
     \\
     \hline 
      Time & Velocity & $|p|$ if $m=1.19kg$  & Time & Velocity & $|p|$ if $m=1.77kg$ \\
     \hline 
      0.48 s & 1.04 $m/s& $ $1.24 N\cdot s$  &0.53 s & 0.94 $m/s$ & 1.67 $ N\cdot s$ \\
     
     \hline 
      0.37 s &  1.35$m/s $ & $ 1.61 $N\cdot s$  &0.48 s & 1.04 $m/s$ & 1.84$ N\cdot s$ \\
      
      \hline 
      0.3 s & 1.67 $m/s& $ 1.98 $N\cdot s$  &0.54 s & 0.93 $m/s$ & $ 1.64 N\cdot s$ \\
      
      \hline 
      0.31 s & 1.62 $m/s& $ 1.92 $N\cdot s$  &0.51 s & 0.98 $m/s$ & $ 1.73 N\cdot s
      \\
      \hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1.0cm}  
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! You missed the column separator in the first row. Also, I think you should consider removing the extra vertical lines and don't place column separator (`&`) within `$$`.

Comment: Also, I think you haven't placed `$$` correctly in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

You have mismatch in pairing of (about 10)  `$` for math environments. Correcting your code fragment (extended to MWE (Minimal Working Example)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{center} 
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c | c|c|c|} 
    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Mass 1} &    \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Mass 2} \\ 
    \hline 
Time & Velocity & $|p|$ if $m=1.19kg$ & Time & Velocity & $|p|$ if $m=1.77kg$ \\
    \hline
0.48 s & 1.04 $m/s$ & $1.24 N\cdot s$ & 0.53 s & 0.94 $m/s$ & 1.67 $ N\cdot s$ \\
    \hline
0.37 s &  1.35$m/s $ &  1.61 $N\cdot s$  &0.48 s & 1.04 $m/s$ & 1.84$ N\cdot s$ \\
    \hline
0.3 s & 1.67 $m/s$ &  1.98 $N\cdot s$  &0.54 s & 0.93 $m/s$ & $1.64 N\cdot s$   \\
    \hline
0.31 s & 1.62 $m/s$ & 1.92 $N\cdot s$  &0.51 s & 0.98 $m/s$ & $ 1.73 N\cdot s $  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

produce

[image]

This table is not very nice. I would employ `siunitx` package for writing values and also `S` columns type.

**Edit (1):**
With employ `mathtools` and `siunitx` your table can become as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center} 
    \sisetup{table-format=1.2,
             per-mode=symbol}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\begin{tabular}{|S|S|S | S|S|S|} 
    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Mass $m=\qty{1.19}{\kilo\gram}$} 
    &    \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Mass $m=\qty{1.77}{\kilo\gram}$} \\
    \hline 
{Time}  
        &   {Velocity (\si{\meter\per\second})}
                &   {$\abs{p}$ (\si{\newton\meter})}
                        &   {Time (\si{\second})}
                                &   {Velocity (\si{\meter\per\second})}
                                        &   {$\abs{p}$  (\si{\newton\meter})} 
                                                    \\
    \hline
0.48    & 1.04  & 1.24  & 0.53  & 0.94  & 1.67      \\
    \hline
0.37    &  1.35 & 1.61  & 0.48  & 1.04  & 1.84      \\
    \hline
0.3     & 1.67  & 1.98  & 0.54  & 0.93  & 1.64      \\
    \hline
0.31    & 1.62  & 1.92  & 0.51  & 0.98  & 1.73      \\
    \hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit (2):**
One more example how you can write your table ... by use of the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx, varwidth}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center} 
    \sisetup{table-format=1.2,
             per-mode=symbol}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={*{6}{Q[c, si]}},
             rowsep=3pt,
, wd=4em]} 
\SetCell[c=3]{c}   {{{Mass, $m=\qty{1.19}{\kilo\gram}$}}}
        &       &       &    \SetCell[c=3]{c}   {{{Mass, $m=\qty{1.77}{\kilo\gram}$}}}
                                &       &           \\
{{{Time (\unit{\second}) }}}
        &   {{{Velocity (\unit{\meter\per\second}) }}}
                &   {{{$\abs{p}$ (\unit{\newton\meter}) }}}
                        &   {{{Time (\unit{\second}) }}}
                                &   {{{Velocity (\unit{\meter\per\second}) }}}
                                        &   {{{$\abs{p}$  (\unit{\newton\meter}) }}} 
                                                    \\
0.48    & 1.04  & 1.24  & 0.53  & 0.94  & 1.67      \\
0.37    & 1.35  & 1.61  & 0.48  & 1.04  & 1.84      \\
0.3     & 1.67  & 1.98  & 0.54  & 0.93  & 1.64      \\
0.31    & 1.62  & 1.92  & 0.51  & 0.98  & 1.73      \\
\end{tblr} 
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks it worked!

Comment: @KouroshHashemi, of course it works, but now with use of `mathtools` and `siunitx` packages is also nicer (and without problems with `$` )

Comment: @KouroshHashemi If you agree with the answer, please vote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to fixing the code that determines how the entries in row 1 of the table are typeset, you may also want to give the table a more attractive and inviting "look", not just for the sake of "pure aesthetics" but also to improve the odds that your readers will actually bother to study the table's contents.

Some suggestions, in no particular order:

- Don't use vertical lines, and use horizontal lines sparingly.
- Remove repetitive things (such as units of measurement) out of the body of the table and place them in the header.
- Make sure the appearance of the header is clear and uncluttered.
- Load the `siunitx` package and use its macros `\unit` and `\qty` to guarantee that scientific units and quantities are typeset in typographically acceptable ways. @Zarko has already made the same point in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622507/5001).

The two tables below implement these suggestions. They differ in one design element only: the column widths (due to differing choices of the underlying column types).

- The upper tabular environment uses the `c` column type, assuring that the table is typeset in a compact way. A downside is that the separation between columns 3 and 4 is noticeably smaller than between other columns.
- The lower tabular environment uses the `w` column type (provided by the `array` package) to assure that the widths of all 6 columns are equal (specifically, equal to the width of the word "Velocity"). A downside of this option (by design!) is that the table's appearance is a bit less compact than if the `c` column type is chosen.

Neither design option creates an "obviously better" outcome. Choose whichever option pleases you more.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type
\newlength\mywidth
\settowidth\mywidth{Velocity} % measure width of widest column header

\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx} % for '\unit' and '\qty' macros

\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \cmidrule and \bottomrule macros

\begin{document}
\begin{center} 

Version 1: minimal column widths\strut

\begin{tabular}{@{} *{6}{c} @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Mass 1: \qty{1.19}{\kilo\gram}} &
\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Mass 2: \qty{1.77}{\kilo\gram}} \\ 
\cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(l){4-6}
 
Time & Velocity & $|p|$ & Time & Velocity & $|p|$ \\
(\unit{\second}) & (\unit{\meter\per\second}) & (\unit{\newton\second}) &
(\unit{\second}) & (\unit{\meter\per\second}) & (\unit{\newton\second})\\
\midrule
0.48 & 1.04 & 1.24 & 0.53 & 0.94 & 1.67 \\
0.37 & 1.35 & 1.61 & 0.48 & 1.04 & 1.84 \\
0.3\hphantom{0}  & 1.67 & 1.98 & 0.54 & 0.93 & 1.64 \\
0.31 & 1.62 & 1.92 & 0.51 & 0.98 & 1.73 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 

\bigskip\bigskip


Version 2: equal column widths\strut

\begin{tabular}{@{} *{6}{wc{\mywidth}} @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Mass 1: \qty{1.19}{\kilo\gram}} &
\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Mass 2: \qty{1.77}{\kilo\gram}} \\ 
\cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(l){4-6}
 
Time & Velocity & $|p|$ & Time & Velocity & $|p|$ \\
(\unit{\second}) & (\unit{\meter\per\second}) & (\unit{\newton\second}) &
(\unit{\second}) & (\unit{\meter\per\second}) & (\unit{\newton\second})\\
\midrule
0.48 & 1.04 & 1.24 & 0.53 & 0.94 & 1.67 \\
0.37 & 1.35 & 1.61 & 0.48 & 1.04 & 1.84 \\
0.3\hphantom{0}  & 1.67 & 1.98 & 0.54 & 0.93 & 1.64 \\
0.31 & 1.62 & 1.92 & 0.51 & 0.98 & 1.73 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you should use *two* tables with subcaptions, but I'll first deal with the “single table strategy”.

You should avoid repeating over and over the units (and be consistent in their representation); this can be done by specifying the unit in the column header.

Figures should be aligned at the decimal point, which is easily accomplished with `siunitx`-provided `S` column type.

Also caging entries should be avoided.

In both tables, since they're quite narrow, I increased somewhat the intercolumn space.

Fix the common caption to better explain what's in the tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} *{6}{S[table-format=1.2]} @{} }
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Mass $m=\qty{1.19}{\kilo\gram}$} &
\multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Mass $m=\qty{1.77}{\kilo\gram}$} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(l){4-6}
{Time} & {Velocity} & $|p|$ & {Time} & {Velocity} & $|p|$ \\
{(\unit{\second})} & {(\unit{\meter\per\second})} & {(\unit{\newton\second})} &
{(\unit{\second})} & {(\unit{\meter\per\second})} & {(\unit{\newton\second})} \\
\midrule
0.48 & 1.04 & 1.24 & 0.53 & 0.94 & 1.67 \\
0.37 & 1.35 & 1.61 & 0.48 & 1.04 & 1.84 \\
0.3  & 1.67 & 1.98 & 0.54 & 0.93 & 1.64 \\
0.31 & 1.62 & 1.92 & 0.51 & 0.98 & 1.73 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Comparison of you-know-what with different masses}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}

\subcaptionbox{Mass $m=\qty{1.19}{\kilo\gram}$}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ @{} *{3}{S[table-format=1.2]} @{} }
  \toprule
  {Time} & {Velocity} & $|p|$ \\
  {(\unit{\second})} & {(\unit{\meter\per\second})} & {(\unit{\newton\second})} \\
  \midrule
  0.48 & 1.04 & 1.24 \\
  0.37 & 1.35 & 1.61 \\
  0.3  & 1.67 & 1.98 \\
  0.31 & 1.62 & 1.92 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
}\qquad
\subcaptionbox{Mass $m=\qty{1.77}{\kilo\gram}$}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ @{} *{3}{S[table-format=1.2]} @{} }
  \toprule
  {Time} & {Velocity} & $|p|$ \\
  {(\unit{\second})} & {(\unit{\meter\per\second})} & {(\unit{\newton\second})} \\
  \midrule
  0.53 & 0.94 & 1.67 \\
  0.48 & 1.04 & 1.84 \\
  0.54 & 0.93 & 1.64 \\
  0.51 & 0.98 & 1.73 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
}

\caption{Comparison of you-know-what with different masses}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want a caged table:

```
\begin{tabular}{ | *{6}{S[table-format=1.2]|} }
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Mass $m=\qty{1.19}{\kilo\gram}$} &
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Mass $m=\qty{1.77}{\kilo\gram}$} \\
\hline
{Time} & {Velocity} & $|p|$ & {Time} & {Velocity} & $|p|$ \\
{(\unit{\second})} & {(\unit{\meter\per\second})} & {(\unit{\newton\second})} &
{(\unit{\second})} & {(\unit{\meter\per\second})} & {(\unit{\newton\second})} \\
\hline
0.48 & 1.04 & 1.24 & 0.53 & 0.94 & 1.67 \\
\hline
0.37 & 1.35 & 1.61 & 0.48 & 1.04 & 1.84 \\
\hline
0.3  & 1.67 & 1.98 & 0.54 & 0.93 & 1.64 \\
\hline
0.31 & 1.62 & 1.92 & 0.51 & 0.98 & 1.73 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]